# C++ define 3 arguments but using just 2

Tags: c++, class, constructor, arguments

I would like to use different number of arguments.

```
class A {
    public:
          A(int a, int b);
};

A::A(int a, int b) {
    // constructor code
}

int main() { 
    A a(5); // I use only 1 argument and the second one I let default ?
}
```

Comment: use like `A(int a, int b =5);`. any default value you can give at declaration time.

Comment: Two options: default argument (see duplicate question) or overloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors are (a bit special) functions - regular default parameter syntax applies.

```
class A {
    public:
          A(int a, int b = default_value);
};

A::A(int a, int b) {
    // constructor code
}

int main() { 
    A a(5);
}
```